# Multiply parent doc _score and the _score from function_score with nested query

Tags: elasticsearch

What I want is to get all documents which match query terms in Title field, and boost the score by value of a field in nested object if the query term also exactly match that nested field.

Following is my example doc:

```
{
  "Title": "The Heart of the Elastic Stack"
  "QueryClicks": [
      { "Term": "elastic stack", "Count": 100},
      { "Term": "elastic", "Count": 50},
      { "Term": "hard of the elastic", "Count": 200},
  ]
}
```

And example query DSL:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
          "match" : {
            "Title" : "elastic stack"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should" : [{
          "nested" : {
            "path" : "QueryClicks",
            "query" : {
              "function_score" : {
                "query" : {
                  "match" : {
                    "QueryClicks.Term.lowercaseraw" : "elastic stack"
                  }
                },
                "functions" : [{
                    "script_score" : {
                      "script" : "log(doc['QueryClicks.Count'].value*4)"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "boost_mode" : "replace"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It somehow works, for certain queryterm, if it match one of the QueryClicks.Term, extra scores will be added to the whole score of the document.

But not perfect, what I want is to multiply the nested function score (that is, log(doc['QueryClicks.Count'].value*4) ) with the parent document's score which calculated in must clause.

If I can get the parent doc's score, then I can do something like this:

"script": "log(doc['QueryClicks.Count'].value*4) * _parent_score"

But since ES does not support getting parent score from nested query yet. Any other approaches?

The purpose is, multiply the _score which calculated by QueryClicks.Count and the _score from must query clause.

Comment: in order to multiply function score with query score boost_mode should be multiply.

Answer (score 1):

You have used boost_mode as replace. This will neglect your score generated by query. Your current settings for function score will replace score  of document with that [score of function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query only.

To multiply both the score of function query and score generated by query use the following query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "Title": "elastic stack"
                }
            }],
            "should": [{
                "nested": {
                    "path": "QueryClicks",
                    "query": {
                        "function_score": {
                            "query": {
                                "match": {
                                    "QueryClicks.Term.lowercaseraw": "elastic stack"
                                }
                            },
                            "functions": [{
                                "script_score": {
                                    "script": "log(doc['QueryClicks.Count'].value*4)"
                                }
                            }],
                            "boost_mode": "multiply",
                            "score_mode": "sum"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can replace score_mode accordingly how you want to evaluate the function score for each score inside the function.

Hope this works for you.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. Changing "boost_mode" to multiply in function_score clause just multiply the score from script_score and the score from the **nested** match query of function_score. Then add to the score from parent query. What I want is, multiply the score from script_score and the score from **parent** query.

Comment: ok.first of all score_mode is for combining the scores of all functions inside function array. boost_mode is for combining the score of function with query score. Now you say you want the score from script_score(means you want to neglect nested score). Function score only consider score from function array, query inside function score is only to filter the documents to subset for function to apply. It is very clearly mentioned in ES doc "The newly computed score is combined with the score of the query. The parameter boost_mode defines how:". So i think this pretty much solves your said problem

Comment: also please attach query explain to see how scores are working for you. you can shoot the query with extra query param like "POST play1/_search?explain". please paste the output

Comment: it is hard to post the detailed explanation in comments, so I have to post my answer in below "answer"

Comment: ok, i will try to understand your problem and edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, now you can check my detailed explanation in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
I did not answer your questions clearly in previous comments. I try to explain with more details.
You are right that score_mode is for combining the **scores of all function**s inside function array and boost_mode is for combining the **score of function with query score**.

And what I want is:

1. Multiply the score of parent doc and the score of nested doc.
2. The parent doc score is from the **{match: {"Title": "elastic stack"}}** in **must** clause.
3. The nested doc score is calculated by nested doc field QueryClicks.Count, which is wrapped in function_score in nested query in **should** clause.

So, in my original query DSL, I set boost_mode to **"replace"**, coz the score I want in **should** clause is actually the score from following script:

```
"script": "log(doc['QueryClicks.Count'].value*4)"
```

But since it is in **should** clause, it will be added to the score from **must** clause. As I said, I want it is multiplied to score from **must** clause.

If change **"boost_mode"** to "multiply" as you suggested, the script score will be multiplied to the score from nested match:
**"match": {"QueryClicks.Term.lowercaseraw": "elastic stack"}**

The associated query (**"match": {"QueryClicks.Term.lowercaseraw": "elastic stack"}**) of the above script_score is just the precondition of using the script score.

Then this score will be added to the score from **must** clause. This is not what I want.

Hope this help you understand my requirement.